# Is there a replacement for the RequestInterceptor in Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-networking, okhttp

I ran into a problem that `RequestInterceptor` has been removed from the **Retrofit 2**. Earlier, my RestAdapter builder was as follows:

```
private RestAdapter.Builder getBuilder(RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor) {
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.SERVER_URL)
            .setClient(connectionClient)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .setConverter(new JacksonConverter());
    return builder;
}
```

As far as I know, at the moment it's recommended to use `interceptor` from the `OkHttp` library instead of the `RequestInterceptor`.

I couldn't find the exemplary implementation of this approach, therefore, be grateful for any help in this matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

intercepts have to be set through `OkHttp` in retrofit 2

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(...)
```

and then register it to Retrofit

```
Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Interceptors can be added to client itself.

```
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(...)
```

When you are executing this line.You are actually adding your own interceptor into existing list of interceptors already added into client.

You can create your own interceptor

```
public class HttpLoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private final static String TAG = LogUtils.makeLogTag(HttpLoggingInterceptor.class);

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    LOGD(TAG, "**********************       REQUEST START     **********************");
    LOGD(TAG, "REQUEST URL -> "+request.urlString());
    LOGD(TAG, "REQUEST HEADERS -> "+request.headers());
    LOGD(TAG, "**********************       REQUEST END     **********************");


    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());


    LOGD(TAG, "**********************       RESPONSE START     **********************");
    LOGD(TAG, "RESPONSE CODE -> "+response.code());
    LOGD(TAG, "RESPONSE HEADERS -> "+response.headers());
    LOGD(TAG, "**********************       RESPONSE END     **********************");
    return response;
}
```

}

and then plugin/add it to client any time before building service

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new HttpLoggingInterceptor());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(okHttpClient).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```